# Can I add another Azure subscription to my personal directory?

Tags: azure, subscription

I have created a personal Azure subscription so I have an AD called firstnamelastnamecompanycom.onmicrosoft.com. Bound to that AD I have a subscription called Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN. This I think is how all subscriptions are created.

Can I create a new (pay-as-you-go) subscription bound to that AD?

Background:
I installed some VMs on my subscription for our development team and I would now like to move those VMs to another subscription. VM's can only be moved another subscription that is backed by the same AD. So if I create a new subscription I can move the servers there. Then I can move the whole subscription to another account in the portal. I hope.

Comment: Of course, you can. You can have multiple subscriptions in one tenant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create another subscription in the same AD tenant just log in to the portal and go to the subscriptions resource. This is the screen that will show you a list of all your subscriptions. There is an Add button on the top of the page. If you click that and walk through the process it should add a new subscription linked to the AD directory you currently have in context in the portal.

Even if it doesn't create the subscription in the correct AD tenant, you can change it by going to the subscription in the Azure portal and selecting "Change Directory" off the overview tab.

Another route is to log into account.azure.com and add the subscription from there. You can also rename the subscriptions to make them more meaningful to you.